# VBA not displaying comparison outcome

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to VBA but basically, I am have 4 excel sheet in the same directory they have identical headers, just differ in values, I am trying to compare them and retrieve the results on the current excel sheet where I run my VBA command. At the same time, there's unnecessary rows I won't need and want it to be removed. Basically the algorithm and calculation works. Because I have logged it and I checked it works. However, the comparison outcome is not showing. Every time I run this command it just generate a log but my current excel is still blank. Can someone advise me what I am doing wrong.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareAndModifyFiles()
    ' Disable unnecessary Excel settings for performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim logFilePath As String
    Dim logFileNumber As Integer
    Dim wbA As Workbook, wbB As Workbook, wbC As Workbook, wbD As Workbook
    Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dataA As Variant, dataB As Variant, dataC As Variant, dataD As Variant
    Dim maxVal As Variant, minVal As Variant, avgVal As Variant
    Dim columnToCheck As Long
    
    ' Set the file path
    filePath = "C:\Users\kelvin.how\Downloads\"
    logFilePath = filePath & "Log.txt"
    
    ' Open or create the log file
    logFileNumber = FreeFile
    Open logFilePath For Output As logFileNumber
    
    ' Log the start of the operation
    LogMessage logFileNumber, "Comparison and Modification Operation - Start: " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
    
    ' Open each workbook
    Set wbA = Workbooks.Open(filePath & "a.xlsx")
    Set wbB = Workbooks.Open(filePath & "b.xlsx")
    Set wbC = Workbooks.Open(filePath & "c.xlsx")
    Set wbD = Workbooks.Open(filePath & "d.xlsx")
    
    ' Loop through each sheet in each workbook
    For Each wsA In wbA.Sheets
        Set wsB = GetSheetIfExists(wbB, wsA.Name)
        Set wsC = GetSheetIfExists(wbC, wsA.Name)
        Set wsD = GetSheetIfExists(wbD, wsA.Name)
        
        ' Check if corresponding sheets exist in all workbooks
        If Not (wsB Is Nothing) And Not (wsC Is Nothing) And Not (wsD Is Nothing) Then
            ' Read data into arrays
            dataA = wsA.UsedRange.Value
            dataB = wsB.UsedRange.Value
            dataC = wsC.UsedRange.Value
            dataD = wsD.UsedRange.Value
            
            ' Delete specified columns
            dataA = DeleteColumnsFromArray(dataA, Array(2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, _
                                                        31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, _
                                                        52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57))
            
            ' Loop through each row in the specified range
            For i = 2 To UBound(dataA, 1)
                ' Compare values and modify accordingly
                For columnToCheck = LBound(dataA, 2) To UBound(dataA, 2)
                    If columnToCheck <= UBound(dataB, 2) And _
                       columnToCheck <= UBound(dataC, 2) And _
                       columnToCheck <= UBound(dataD, 2) Then
                       
                        maxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dataA(i, columnToCheck), _
                                                                   dataB(i, columnToCheck), _
                                                                   dataC(i, columnToCheck), _
                                                                   dataD(i, columnToCheck))
                       
                        minVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(dataA(i, columnToCheck), _
                                                                   dataB(i, columnToCheck), _
                                                                   dataC(i, columnToCheck), _
                                                                   dataD(i, columnToCheck))
                       
                        avgVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(dataA(i, columnToCheck), _
                                                                       dataB(i, columnToCheck), _
                                                                       dataC(i, columnToCheck), _
                                                                       dataD(i, columnToCheck))
                       
                        ' Modify the data in the array
                        If maxVal = minVal And minVal = avgVal Then
                            LogMessage logFileNumber, "Row " & i & ", Column " & columnToCheck & ": Values are the same across all workbooks"
                        Else
                            ' Values differ, modify accordingly
                            LogMessage logFileNumber, "Row " & i & ", Column " & columnToCheck & ": Values differ - Max: " & maxVal & ", Min: " & minVal & ", Avg: " & avgVal
                            dataA(i, columnToCheck) = IIf(columnToCheck = 37, IIf(IsNumeric(avgVal), avgVal, ""), _
                                                          IIf(columnToCheck = 38, IIf(IsNumeric(minVal), minVal, ""), _
                                                          IIf(columnToCheck = 39, IIf(IsNumeric(maxVal), maxVal, ""), "")))
                        End If
                    End If
                Next columnToCheck
            Next i
            
            ' Write modified data back to the worksheet
            wsA.UsedRange.Value = dataA
        Else
            LogMessage logFileNumber, "Sheets not found in all workbooks: " & wsA.Name
        End If
    Next wsA
    
    ' Close workbooks without saving changes
    wbA.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wbB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wbC.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wbD.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Log the end of the operation
    LogMessage logFileNumber, "Comparison and Modification Operation - End: " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
    
    ' Close the log file
    Close logFileNumber
    
    ' Enable Excel settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub LogMessage(logFileNumber As Integer, message As String)
    ' Alternative log message function
    Print #logFileNumber, message
    Debug.Print message ' This will also print the message to the immediate window for debugging purposes
End Sub

Function GetSheetIfExists(wb As Workbook, sheetName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheetIfExists = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function GetNumericValue(value As Variant) As Variant
    ' Modified to return actual numeric values
    If IsNumeric(value) Then
        GetNumericValue = value
    Else
        GetNumericValue = 0  ' Change this to whatever default numeric value you want
    End If
End Function

Function DeleteColumnsFromArray(dataArray As Variant, columnsToDelete As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim newDataArray As Variant
    
    ReDim newDataArray(1 To UBound(dataArray, 1), 1 To UBound(dataArray, 2) - UBound(columnsToDelete))
    
    For i = LBound(dataArray, 1) To UBound(dataArray, 1)
        For j = LBound(dataArray, 2) To UBound(dataArray, 2)
            If Not IsInArray(j, columnsToDelete) Then
                newDataArray(i, j - (j > UBound(columnsToDelete))) = dataArray(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    DeleteColumnsFromArray = newDataArray
End Function

Function IsInArray(value As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = value Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Are you expecting the comparison outcome in `dataA` ? You're closing that without saving.

Comment: @CLR nope I'm expecting the comparison outcome in the current working excel worksheet where I run this macro. Anyway I found an alternative solution; simply create separate buttons for each calculations and algorithms instead of running the macro in one go.

Comment: "The comparison outcome is not showing" - that would suggest you've attempted to retrieve the outcome. However, nothing (that I can see) in your code writes back to the active worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Simply create multiple buttons with macro performing separate different individual calculations and algorithms for each buttons.

i.e. Button for ECS

```
Sub ECS()
    Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

' Set the current worksheet
Set wsCurrent = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' Open the source workbook
Dim sourceFilePath As String
sourceFilePath = "C:\Users\kelvin.how\Downloads\a.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open sourceFilePath
Set wsSource = Workbooks("a.xlsx").Worksheets(1) ' Assuming data is on the first sheet

' Find the last row in column A of the source worksheet
lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Copy data from A4 to the last row in column A of the source worksheet
wsSource.Range("A4:A" & lastRow).Copy
wsCurrent.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' Copy data from D4 to the last row in column D of the source worksheet
wsSource.Range("D4:D" & lastRow).Copy
wsCurrent.Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' Copy data from E4 to the last row in column E of the source worksheet
wsSource.Range("E4:E" & lastRow).Copy
wsCurrent.Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' Copy data from F4 to the last row in column F of the source worksheet
wsSource.Range("F4:F" & lastRow).Copy
wsCurrent.Range("D3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' Copy data from G4 to the last row in column G of the source worksheet
wsSource.Range("G4:G" & lastRow).Copy
wsCurrent.Range("E3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' Close the source workbook without saving changes
Workbooks("a.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Button for CPU

```
 Sub CPU()
    Dim path As String
    Dim files As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Long

' Set the path to the directory containing the files
path = "C:\Users\kelvin.how\Downloads\"

' List of file names to compare
files = Array("a.xlsx", "b.xlsx", "c.xlsx", "d.xlsx")

' Set up the main workbook and worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Assuming the macro is in the workbook where you want to copy data
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) ' Assuming data is on the first sheet

' Loop through each file
For i = 0 To UBound(files)
    ' Open each workbook
    Set externalWb = Workbooks.Open(path & files(i))
    
    ' Find the last row in column L, M, and N
    lastRow = externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(externalWb.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Compare and copy data from column L to column F
    For j = 4 To lastRow
        ws.Cells(j - 1, "F").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Cells(j - 1, "F").Value, externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "L").Value)
    Next j
    
    ' Initialize minimum value in column G
    For j = 4 To lastRow
        ws.Cells(j - 1, "G").Value = IIf(i = 0, externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "M").Value, _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Cells(j - 1, "G").Value, externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "M").Value))
    Next j
    
    ' Accumulate values for average calculation
    For j = 1 To lastRow - 3
        ws.Cells(j + 2, "H").Value = (ws.Cells(j + 2, "H").Value * i + externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j + 3, "N").Value) / (i + 1)
    Next j
    
    ' Close the external workbook
    externalWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next i
End Sub
```

Button for Memory

```
Sub Memory()
    Dim path As String
    Dim files As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Long
    
    ' Set the path to the directory containing the files
    path = "C:\Users\kelvin.how\Downloads\"
    
    ' List of file names to compare
    files = Array("a.xlsx", "b.xlsx", "c.xlsx", "d.xlsx")
    
    ' Set up the main workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Assuming the macro is in the workbook where you want to copy data
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) ' Assuming data is on the first sheet
    
    ' Loop through each file
    For i = 0 To UBound(files)
        ' Open each workbook
        Set externalWb = Workbooks.Open(path & files(i))
        
        ' Find the last row in column Q, R, and S
        lastRow = externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(externalWb.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Compare and copy data from column Q to column I
        For j = 4 To lastRow
            ws.Cells(j - 1, "I").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Cells(j - 1, "I").Value, externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "Q").Value)
        Next j
        
        ' Compare and copy data from column R to column J
        For j = 4 To lastRow
            If i = 0 Then
                ws.Cells(j - 1, "J").Value = externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "R").Value
            Else
                ws.Cells(j - 1, "J").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Cells(j - 1, "J").Value, externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "R").Value)
            End If
        Next j
        
        ' Calculate average data from column S to column K
        For j = 4 To lastRow
            ws.Cells(j - 1, "K").Value = (ws.Cells(j - 1, "K").Value * i + externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "S").Value) / (i + 1)
        Next j
        
        ' Close the external workbook
        externalWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Button for Total

```
Sub Total()
    Dim path As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim afValue As Double
    Dim akValue As Double
    Dim result As Double
    
    ' Set the path to the directory containing the file
    path = "C:\Users\kelvin.how\Downloads\"
    
    ' Set up the main workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Assuming the macro is in the workbook where you want to copy data
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) ' Assuming data is on the first sheet
    
    ' Open the workbook for calculation
    Set externalWb = Workbooks.Open(path & "a.xlsx")
    
    ' Find the last row in column AF and AK
    lastRow = externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(externalWb.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Perform the calculation and copy the rounded-up values to column L
    For j = 4 To lastRow
        afValue = externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "AF").Value
        akValue = externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "AK").Value
        
        ' Check if AK is greater than zero before performing the calculation
        If akValue > 0 Then
            result = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(afValue / (akValue / 100), 10)
        Else
            ' If AK is zero or negative, set the result to zero
            result = 0
        End If
        
        ' Copy the result to column L
        ws.Cells(j - 1, "L").Value = result
    Next j
    
    ' Close the external workbook
    externalWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Button for Storage

```
Sub Storage()
    Dim path As String
    Dim files As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Long
    
    ' Set the path to the directory containing the files
    path = "C:\Users\kelvin.how\Downloads\"
    
    ' List of file names to compare
    files = Array("a.xlsx", "b.xlsx", "c.xlsx", "d.xlsx")
    
    ' Set up the main workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Assuming the macro is in the workbook where you want to copy data
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) ' Assuming data is on the first sheet
    
    ' Loop through each file
    For i = 0 To UBound(files)
        ' Open each workbook
        Set externalWb = Workbooks.Open(path & files(i))
        
        ' Find the last row in column AK, AL, and AM
        lastRow = externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(externalWb.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Compare and copy data from column AK to column M
        For j = 4 To lastRow
            ws.Cells(j - 1, "M").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Cells(j - 1, "M").Value, externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "AK").Value)
        Next j
        
        ' Initialize minimum value in column N
        For j = 4 To lastRow
            If i = 0 Then
                ws.Cells(j - 1, "N").Value = externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "AL").Value
            Else
                ws.Cells(j - 1, "N").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Cells(j - 1, "N").Value, externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "AL").Value)
            End If
        Next j
        
        ' Initialize values for average calculation in column O
        For j = 4 To lastRow
            ws.Cells(j - 1, "O").Value = ws.Cells(j - 1, "O").Value + externalWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "AM").Value
        Next j
        
        ' Close the external workbook
        externalWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next i
    
    ' Calculate average values in column O
    For j = 4 To lastRow
        ws.Cells(j - 1, "O").Value = ws.Cells(j - 1, "O").Value / (UBound(files) + 1)
    Next j
End Sub
```